# How to migrate Ehcache to Infinispan Cache in Spring 3.0.2 with Hibernate 3.6.3?

Tags: spring, hibernate, ehcache, infinispan

I am facing a performance issue with Ehcache. I believe that migrating to Infinispan Cache would solve the performance issues. How can I do this?

We are facing the performance issue in the class  net.sf.ehcache.Cache.get(Serializable).

Please find below configuration:

Libraries:

hibernate3.jar
hibernate-core.3.6.3.jar
spring 3.2.0 jars

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">
true
</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">
true
</prop>
```

Comment: Hi, could you narrow down the issue please? Feel free to follow - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is a classic case of "Too Broad" and is unlikely to get you any useful replies. Always make sure that when you ask a question, it is sufficiently narrow to give readers an idea of your use case and what you have tried already.

Comment: your question is way to broad as alreayd noted. however ive used ehcache for years and recently used infinispan(because it allows persistence between JVM restarts) the performance increase was not really noticeable for my dataset.

Comment: Yes. Can you please state the performance issue so we can help you? Directly jumping to some other framework is a bit of a strong move.

Comment: We are performance issue in the class net.sf.ehcache.Cache.get(Serializable). Please find below configuration.

Comment: I have given the configuration for the performance issue. Please help me on solving the issue.

Comment: Hi All, I have given the class and method name where it's taking more time. Please help me on solving that performance issue. It's very critical and I need to complete it ASAP.